# Error using python with terminal after installing python 3.6 using macports

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, terminal, macports

I use macports to install packages on my laptop.  I have used it to set up and install a python environment (version 2.7).  Upon installing python27 and using macports to set python the command to point to the python27 I am able, in the terminal to type:

```
:~ python
```

which correctly opens a python environment in my terminal session, where I can execute python commands.

When I follow the same process using macports to install a python 3.6 environment and type the command:

```
:~ python3
```

The environment loads correctly, however if I try to run **any** command in this environment, such as:

```
>>> print('Hello')
```

I get the following error:

```
>>> print('Hello')
Python(24202,0x7fffc0d003c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x10a78f110: 
pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

This only occurs when I use the terminal python environment.  For all intents and purposes, the install runs fine and I am able to run python 3 programs on my system and things like IPython work fine.  This is a specific problem for when I enter the python3 terminal environment after installing it using macports.

I would like to know, what causes this to happen and is there a way I can fix it?

I have tried commands like:

```
port diagnose
```

and removing the port, all related ports and reinstalling but I am presented with the exact same error.  Does anyone else experience this or have a resolution for it?

Comment: this may help: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48807  check the very bottom

Comment: This solved my problem.  I'll mark it as an answer if you want to respond to the question, else I'll write it up myself so that it's easy to find for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check out this link [#48807](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48807), it is a known issue and below lines are quoted from the thread:

> Just installed python36 and the install recommend py36-readline and had malloc crashes along the lines of pointer being freed was not allocated python.
>
> Found this thread. Uninstalled py36-readline and installed python36 +readline, which seems to have fixed this.